# When i hover over an img other images and borders appear on top of it

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

When i hover over an image any subsequent any image and border will render on top of the image.

**Before hovering:**
[image: Before Hovering]

**While hovering:**
[image]

Im using react and tailwind, and im fairly new to both, i have tried changing the z-index but it seems to do nothing, images that appear before the image being hovered do show up properly, meaning below the image, how do i fix this?

My code:

**App.js**

```
//code to get images of cats would go here, just ignore that.
function App() {

  function getRandomInt() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
  }

  const kitten = generateKittenUrls();

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row-reverse">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className='flex flex-col align-middle w-full py-20'>
        <div className='px-40 mb-20'>
          <h1 className='text-9xl font-bold align-middle justify-center flex mb-10'><span>CUE</span></h1>
          <span className='text-center'>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</span>
        </div>
        <div className='flex flex-row flex-wrap align-middle justify-center md:mx-10 items-start'>
          <div className='flex flex-col align-middle justify-center space-y-10'>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
          </div>
          <div className='flex flex-col align-middle justify-center space-y-10'>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Gallery.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Gallery(props) {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsHovered(true);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovered(false);
  };

  return (
    <a
      href="#"
      className={`border border-newgrey p-5 w-max h-max max-w-2xl relative z-0 ${isHovered ? '' : ''}`}
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
    >
      <img
        className={`object-scale-down transition filter z-10 ${isHovered ? 'scale-125 brightness-50' : ''}`}
        src={props.portrait}
        alt=""
      />
      <h2
        className={`absolute bottom-2/4 left-2/4 text-5xl transition opacity-0 ${isHovered ? 'text-white scale-125 opacity-100' : ''}`}
      >
        Cat
      </h2>
    </a>
  );
}

export default Gallery;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing to understand about stacking contexts here is that z indices are *relative* within their own [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context). So the `z-20` of the `<img>` elements are only relative to to other elements **inside** the `<a>` element, which is the stacking context that the `<img>` is in.

Hence, we need to increase the `z-index` of the stacking contexts themselves when hovered:

```js
function Gallery(props) {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = React.useState(false);

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsHovered(true);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovered(false);
  };

  return (
    <a
      href="#"
      className={`border border-newgrey p-5 w-max h-max max-w-2xl relative ${isHovered ? 'z-10' : ''}`}
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
    >
      <img
        className={`object-scale-down transition filter z-10 ${isHovered ? 'scale-125 brightness-50' : ''}`}
        src={props.portrait}
        alt=""
      />
      <h2
        className={`absolute bottom-2/4 left-2/4 text-5xl transition opacity-0 ${isHovered ? 'text-white scale-125 opacity-100' : ''}`}
      >
        Cat
      </h2>
    </a>
  );
}

const generateKittenUrls = () => Array(2000)
  .fill()
  .map((_, i) => `https://picsum.photos/200/400?${i}`);

//code to get images of cats would go here, just ignore that.
function App() {

  function getRandomInt() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
  }

  const kitten = generateKittenUrls();

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row-reverse">
      <div className='flex flex-col align-middle w-full py-20'>
        <div className='px-40 mb-20'>
          <h1 className='text-9xl font-bold align-middle justify-center flex mb-10'><span>CUE</span></h1>
          <span className='text-center'>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</span>
        </div>
        <div className='flex flex-row flex-wrap align-middle justify-center md:mx-10 items-start'>
          <div className='flex flex-col align-middle justify-center space-y-10'>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
          </div>
          <div className='flex flex-col align-middle justify-center space-y-10'>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

However, observe that the borders from other elements still overlap when mouse leave is triggered. This is because the `z-10` class would be removed prematurely. We can keep the `z-10` class on the element until the transition animation completes by having a separate state that listens for the [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event) event before removing the class:

```js
function Gallery(props) {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = React.useState(false);
  const [onTop, setOnTop] = React.useState(false);

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsHovered(true);
    setOnTop(true);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovered(false);
  };
  
  const onTransitionEnd = () => {
    setOnTop(false);
  };

  return (
    <a
      href="#"
      className={`border border-newgrey p-5 w-max h-max max-w-2xl relative ${onTop ? 'z-10' : ''}`}
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
      onTransitionEnd={!isHovered && onTransitionEnd}
    >
      <img
        className={`object-scale-down transition filter z-10 ${isHovered ? 'scale-125 brightness-50' : ''}`}
        src={props.portrait}
        alt=""
      />
      <h2
        className={`absolute bottom-2/4 left-2/4 text-5xl transition opacity-0 ${isHovered ? 'text-white scale-125 opacity-100' : ''}`}
      >
        Cat
      </h2>
    </a>
  );
}

const generateKittenUrls = () => Array(2000)
  .fill()
  .map((_, i) => `https://picsum.photos/200/400?${i}`);

//code to get images of cats would go here, just ignore that.
function App() {

  function getRandomInt() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
  }

  const kitten = generateKittenUrls();

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row-reverse">
      <div className='flex flex-col align-middle w-full py-20'>
        <div className='px-40 mb-20'>
          <h1 className='text-9xl font-bold align-middle justify-center flex mb-10'><span>CUE</span></h1>
          <span className='text-center'>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</span>
        </div>
        <div className='flex flex-row flex-wrap align-middle justify-center md:mx-10 items-start'>
          <div className='flex flex-col align-middle justify-center space-y-10'>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
          </div>
          <div className='flex flex-col align-middle justify-center space-y-10'>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
            <Gallery portrait={kitten[getRandomInt()]}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```